# Как с помощью очереди пройти по дереву файлов?

Tags: java

Есть вот такой метод

```
public static List<String> getFileTree(String root) throws IOException {
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

File rootFile = new File(root);

if (rootFile.isDirectory()) {
  File[] files = rootFile.listFiles();

  if (files != null) {
    for (File tmp : files) {
      if (tmp.isDirectory()) {

        // Вот тут нужно складывать в очередь

      } else {
        result.add(tmp.getAbsolutePath());
      }
    }
  }
}

return result;
}
```

Нужно реализовать логику метода getFileTree, который должен в директории root найти список всех файлов включая вложенные.

Нужно использовать очередь.

Так я могу представить как это сделать с рекурсией и не пойму как выполнить это с очередью

---

Вот условие задания

> Находим все файлы
>   Реализовать логику метода getFileTree, который должен в директории root найти список всех файлов включая вложенные.
>   Используй очередь, рекурсию не используй.
>   Верни список всех путей к найденным файлам, путь к директориям возвращать не надо.
>   Путь должен быть абсолютный.
>
> Требования:
>
> 1. Метод getFileTree должен принимать аргументом String root, по которому нужно найти все вложенные файлы.
>
> 2. Метод getFileTree должен возвращать список строк.
>
> 3. Нужно реализовать метод getFileTree: найти все файлы по указанному пути и добавить их в список.
>
> 4. Метод getFileTree должен быть вызван только 1 раз (рекурсию не использовать).

и вот так выглядит метод сначала

```
public static List<String> getFileTree(String root) throws IOException {

return null;
}
```

Comment: а почему вы считаете что это возможно, то есть откуда возникла такая идея? Может быть вам просто идти рекурсивно складывая в очередь?

Comment: Очередь? Очередь потоков может? Тогда та же самая рекурсия, только задавай вызов этого метода в новом задании потока. Или какая то другая очередь?

Comment: @Павел это задание ... условие я добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Tachkin это задание... условие я добавил в вопрос

Comment: На сколько я понял задание, то от тебя требуется переход от рекурсивного обхода директорий к итеративному, т.е. создать какую то очередь fifo и вызывать по ней один и тот же метод. Как правильно то было, узнал уже?

Comment: @Tachkin еще нет( я делаю другие задания, хотя по твоему ответу все равно не совсем понял как это должно выглядеть